# What is the solution to the Google Calendar - Outlook sync, Windows outdated Time Zone problem?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar, google-sync

I have a well known problem: [You seem to have outdated time zone information. Please run Windows Update.](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=94022#)

Windows Update does not fix the problem.

The there is [Google Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=586617d97e1dbf6c&hl=en) answer that references a [Experts Exchange solution](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Q_24274706.html).  Is there a way to get that solution without joining?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the .reg file from the Experts Exchange solution:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2GujErOC9zdMzBhYzg1YjEtYThhNy00ZTc2LWE1NTItODgyOWY2ZGNhOWMy

It did fix the issue for me.

---

See also the full content of the reg file, on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/DAMWhjVt).

Answer (score 0):

To view EE questions simply type the title of the question into Google and view their cached version of the page.

Comment: This answer had a download file that doesn't seem to be accessible. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: If you right click the EE link, and copy the path then paste the path into a Google and search for that as a string it will be the first return.  On the first return, click cached, then scroll all the way the way down the page to view the content.